How to Resolve "Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write" Error when Requesting Write Access via OAuth?
Question Description:
I am developing an application that integrates with Stack Overflow’s API, and I need to enable write access for it. I’ve successfully registered my application on the Stack Apps site, and I am trying to request OAuth write access with the following URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=26659&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=https://socialmedia.service.clouducaas.com/login_success
However, I keep receiving the error:
"Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write."
Here are the steps I've already followed:

I have registered my app on Stack Apps and obtained my client ID.
I used the correct client_id and redirect_uri.
I included the scope=write_access parameter in my OAuth request.

What could I be missing or doing wrong? How can I resolve this error and successfully enable write access for my application?
Any guidance on how to correctly register the Stack Apps post and link it to my app would be greatly appreciated!

As is stated in bold in the documentation:

Apps must have a registered Stack Apps post to write.

In order to have write access to the SE API, your application/script/library needs to have associated with it a question that you've posted here on Stack Apps which describes your application/script/library.
For applications/scripts/libraries that are in development, it's typical to create a placeholder question which is tagged with placeholder and a title like "PLACEHOLDER - <brief title for your app/script/library>". The body should describe what you're intending to have your app/script/lib do. As part of releasing your application/script/library, this question should be edited into a normal app, script, or library post for your application/script/library.
Once you have such a question describing your application/script/library, the URL for that question should be added to your application's/script's/library's record in the field "Stack Apps Post (optional)".
So, the actions you need to take are:

Create a question here on Stack Apps describing your application/script/library, typically first a placeholder, "PLACEHOLDER - <brief title for your app/script/library>", which you eventually edit into a full post upon release of your application/script/library.
Edit the "Stack Apps Post (optional)" field in your application's/script's/library's record  to have the URL for the question you created in 1 (above).

Once you've done those two steps, you should be able to use your application/script/library for write access through the SE API.
